CVAT installation failing due to supervisord
Trying to run CVAT on GCP, I am getting error on cvat containers.
as per my initial findings trying to run through the supervisord but somehow it's not finding it's configuration in the container.
Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['run', 'worker.analytics_reports']
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['init', 'run' ,'server']
For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
Yaml file which I was trying to run:
enter link description here
just cloned and try to ran.

Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve]. Seeing the Dockerfile in particular would be useful.  I'd generally recommend against using supervisord, since it makes some standard Docker functionality harder to use; what are you trying to run this way, and can you split it into multiple containers?

Hi @DavidMaze, Thanks for responding.  Actually, There nothing I am doing specific! just cloned into GCP instance and then running with docker compose up -d.
Then the cvat_server and related to cvat_server containers just keep on restarting and when I look into the log
Error: positional arguments are not supported: ['run', 'worker.analytics_reports'] For help, use /usr/bin/supervisord -h
